# Jquery causing form not to send one GET variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, get

I have a page (index2.php) that submits to itself, pulling in records from MySQL database and updating prices on a results table.

The coding I have written takes 6 recordsets:
rstCar2 (full list of cars - uses % wildcard)
rstCarsSw (cars with that match  countryid '1')
rstCarsFr (cars with that match  countryid '2')
rstCarsIt (cars with that match  countryid '3')
rstCarsGer (cars with that match  countryid '4')
rstCarsAus (cars with that match  countryid '5')

and displays 6 DIV's each with a list dedicated to one set of cars (each named 'pyt-car') - each list shows the cars available for each country.

The countries are listed with values from from 1-6

So when you select a country, the Jquery changes the CSS so that 5 DIV's are hidden and one is displayed. When you select a different country, the car lists adjust on-the-fly so that a user will only see the cars available for that country.

Initially, you can change the car several times, but once you click a country, it all goes wrong.

After selecting a country, select a car, and click submit, it refuses to change the car, when the page loads, it seems stuck on the selected car.

For some strange reason, Austria (with an id of 5) seems to allow me to change cars, but when I switch to Germany, or any other, it all falls apart.

This is the page in question.... http://www.ultimatedrives.net/plan-your-trip/index2.php

I'm fine with PHP, but a JavaScript/Jquery newbie so this code is probably quite primitive...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>      
 var countryid = "pyt-country = <?php echo $_POST['pyt-country'] ; ?><br/>";
 document.write(countryid);
  var carid = "pyt-car = <?php echo $_POST['pyt-car'] ; ?>";
 document.write(carid);
            if (countryid == "%") {
                        $('.carAll').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
                }
            if (countryid == "1") {
                        $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carSw').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
                }
            if (countryid == "2") {
                        $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carFr').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
                }
            if (countryid == "3") {
                        $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carIt').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
                }
            if (countryid == "4") {
                        $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carGer').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
                }
             if (countryid == "5") {
                        $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                        $('.carAus').css('display', 'block');
                }



$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pyt-country').change(function () {
            if($(this).val() == "%"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if($(this).val() == "1"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if($(this).val() == "2"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if($(this).val() == "3"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if($(this).val() == "4"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if($(this).val() == "5"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });


});  // End eventlistener



</script>

<form action="index2.php" method="post" name="plan-your-trip" id="plan-your-trip">
            <table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
              <tr>
                <td><select name="pyt-country" id="pyt-country">
              <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-country'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-country'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Country...</option>

                    <?php do { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCountry['ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCountry['ID'], $_POST['pyt-country']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCountry['CountryName']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rstCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCountry)); ?>

          </select></td>
                <td>

                <div class="carAll">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                  <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Car...</option>
                  <?php do { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCar2['car_ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCar2['car_ID'], $_POST['pyt-car']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCar2['car_Name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } while ($row_rstCar2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCar2)); ?>
                </select>
                </div>


                  <div class="carSw">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Car...</option>

                    <?php do { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCarsSw['car_ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCarsSw['car_ID'], $_POST['pyt-car']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCarsSw['car_Name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rstCarsSw = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCarsSw)); ?>
                  </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carFr">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Car...</option>

                    <?php do { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCarsFr['car_ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCarsFr['car_ID'], $_POST['pyt-car']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCarsFr['car_Name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rstCarsFr = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCarsFr)); ?>
                  </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carIt">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Car...</option>

                    <?php do { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCarsIt['car_ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCarsIt['car_ID'], $_POST['pyt-car']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCarsIt['car_Name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rstCarsIt = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCarsIt)); ?>
                  </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carGer">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Car...</option>

                    <?php do { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCarsGer['car_ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCarsGer['car_ID'], $_POST['pyt-car']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCarsGer['car_Name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rstCarsGer = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCarsGer)); ?>
                  </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carAus">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-car'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Car...</option>

                    <?php do { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rstCarsAus['car_ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstCarsAus['car_ID'], $_POST['pyt-car']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstCarsAus['car_Name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rstCarsAus = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstCarsAus)); ?>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><select name="pyt-month" id="pyt-month">
                  <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-month'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-month'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Month...</option>
                  <?php
do {  
?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row_rstMonth['mNumber']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstMonth['mNumber'], $_POST['pyt-month']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstMonth['mName']?></option>
                  <?php
} while ($row_rstMonth = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstMonth));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rstMonth);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rstMonth, 0);
      $row_rstMonth = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstMonth);
  }
?>
                </select></td>
                <td><select name="pyt-style" id="pyt-style">
                  <option value="%" <?php if ($_POST['pyt-style'] == '') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?><?php if ($_POST['pyt-style'] == '%') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Any Break Style...</option>
                  <?php do { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row_rstGenre['ID']; ?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rstGenre['ID'], $_POST['pyt-style']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rstGenre['GenreName']; ?></option>
                  <?php } while ($row_rstGenre = mysql_fetch_assoc($rstGenre)); ?>
                </select></td>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Refine Results" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
      </form>
```

When I have selected a car and country, the data looks like this...
pyt-country = 5
pyt-car = 999945

If I change the country to Germany (4) abd select a Ferrari F12 (ID 999980), it then returns this...
pyt-country = 4
pyt-car = 999945

So the country is being sent, but not the car.

The source code looks like this :

```
<form action="index2.php" method="post" name="plan-your-trip" id="plan-your-trip">
            <table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
              <tr>
                <td><select name="pyt-country" id="pyt-country">
              <option value="%" >Any Country...</option>

                                        <option value="1" >Switzerland</option>
                                        <option value="2" >France</option>
                                        <option value="3" >Italy</option>
                                        <option value="4" >Germany</option>
                                        <option value="5" selected="selected">Austria</option>

          </select></td>
                <td>

                <div class="carAll">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                  <option value="%" >Any Car...</option>
                                    <option value="999979" >Aston Martin V12 Vanquish</option>
                                    <option value="999993" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage Coupe</option>
                                    <option value="999925" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage S</option>
                                    <option value="9999100" >Aston Martin Vantage Roadster</option>
                                    <option value="999995" >Aston Martin Virage Volante V12 </option>
                                    <option value="999960" >Audi R8 Spyder V10</option>
                                    <option value="999916" >Audi S5 Cabriolet</option>
                                    <option value="999989" >Audi S5 Sportback</option>
                                    <option value="999951" >Bentley GT V8</option>
                                    <option value="999982" >Bentley GTC V8</option>
                                    <option value="999912" >BMW Z4 sDrive35is </option>
                                    <option value="999931" >Ferrari California</option>
                                    <option value="999980" >Ferrari F12</option>
                                    <option value="999972" >Ferrari F458 Spider</option>
                                    <option value="999996" >Jaguar F-Type V8</option>
                                    <option value="999998" >Lamborghini Aventador</option>
                                    <option value="9999101" selected="selected">Lamborghini Gallardo LP570</option>
                                    <option value="9999102" >Lamborghini Murcielago Roadster LP640</option>
                                    <option value="999981" >McLaren MP4-12C Spider</option>
                                    <option value="999991" >Mercedes CLA 250</option>
                                    <option value="999917" >Mercedes E Class Cabriolet</option>
                                    <option value="999985" >Mercedes SLS Roadster</option>
                                    <option value="999945" >Porsche 911 C2S Cabrio</option>
                                    <option value="999994" >Porsche 911 C2S Coupe</option>
                                    <option value="999920" >Porsche 981 Boxster S</option>
                                    <option value="999984" >Porsche Cayenne S</option>
                                    <option value="999946" >Porsche Panamera GTS</option>
                                    <option value="999969" >Range Rover Evoque</option>
                                    <option value="999938" >Range Rover Sport V8 </option>
                                  </select>
                </div>


                  <div class="carSw">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" >Any Car...</option>

                                        <option value="999993" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage Coupe</option>
                                        <option value="999925" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage S</option>
                                        <option value="9999100" >Aston Martin Vantage Roadster</option>
                                        <option value="999995" >Aston Martin Virage Volante V12 </option>
                                        <option value="999916" >Audi S5 Cabriolet</option>
                                        <option value="999951" >Bentley GT V8</option>
                                        <option value="999931" >Ferrari California</option>
                                        <option value="999980" >Ferrari F12</option>
                                        <option value="999972" >Ferrari F458 Spider</option>
                                        <option value="999996" >Jaguar F-Type V8</option>
                                        <option value="999998" >Lamborghini Aventador</option>
                                        <option value="9999101" selected="selected">Lamborghini Gallardo LP570</option>
                                        <option value="9999102" >Lamborghini Murcielago Roadster LP640</option>
                                        <option value="999917" >Mercedes E Class Cabriolet</option>
                                        <option value="999945" >Porsche 911 C2S Cabrio</option>
                                        <option value="999994" >Porsche 911 C2S Coupe</option>
                                        <option value="999920" >Porsche 981 Boxster S</option>
                                        <option value="999946" >Porsche Panamera GTS</option>
                                        <option value="999969" >Range Rover Evoque</option>
                                      </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carFr">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" >Any Car...</option>

                                        <option value="999960" >Audi R8 Spyder V10</option>
                                        <option value="999982" >Bentley GTC V8</option>
                                        <option value="999931" >Ferrari California</option>
                                        <option value="999980" >Ferrari F12</option>
                                        <option value="999972" >Ferrari F458 Spider</option>
                                        <option value="999996" >Jaguar F-Type V8</option>
                                        <option value="999998" >Lamborghini Aventador</option>
                                        <option value="9999101" selected="selected">Lamborghini Gallardo LP570</option>
                                        <option value="999981" >McLaren MP4-12C Spider</option>
                                        <option value="999985" >Mercedes SLS Roadster</option>
                                        <option value="999945" >Porsche 911 C2S Cabrio</option>
                                        <option value="999920" >Porsche 981 Boxster S</option>
                                      </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carIt">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" >Any Car...</option>

                                        <option value="999993" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage Coupe</option>
                                        <option value="999925" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage S</option>
                                        <option value="9999100" >Aston Martin Vantage Roadster</option>
                                        <option value="999995" >Aston Martin Virage Volante V12 </option>
                                        <option value="999916" >Audi S5 Cabriolet</option>
                                        <option value="999951" >Bentley GT V8</option>
                                        <option value="999931" >Ferrari California</option>
                                        <option value="999980" >Ferrari F12</option>
                                        <option value="999972" >Ferrari F458 Spider</option>
                                        <option value="999996" >Jaguar F-Type V8</option>
                                        <option value="999998" >Lamborghini Aventador</option>
                                        <option value="9999101" selected="selected">Lamborghini Gallardo LP570</option>
                                        <option value="9999102" >Lamborghini Murcielago Roadster LP640</option>
                                        <option value="999917" >Mercedes E Class Cabriolet</option>
                                        <option value="999945" >Porsche 911 C2S Cabrio</option>
                                        <option value="999920" >Porsche 981 Boxster S</option>
                                        <option value="999946" >Porsche Panamera GTS</option>
                                      </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carGer">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" >Any Car...</option>

                                        <option value="999925" >Aston Martin V8 Vantage S</option>
                                        <option value="9999100" >Aston Martin Vantage Roadster</option>
                                        <option value="999916" >Audi S5 Cabriolet</option>
                                        <option value="999951" >Bentley GT V8</option>
                                        <option value="999931" >Ferrari California</option>
                                        <option value="999980" >Ferrari F12</option>
                                        <option value="999972" >Ferrari F458 Spider</option>
                                        <option value="999996" >Jaguar F-Type V8</option>
                                        <option value="999998" >Lamborghini Aventador</option>
                                        <option value="9999101" selected="selected">Lamborghini Gallardo LP570</option>
                                        <option value="9999102" >Lamborghini Murcielago Roadster LP640</option>
                                        <option value="999945" >Porsche 911 C2S Cabrio</option>
                                        <option value="999994" >Porsche 911 C2S Coupe</option>
                                        <option value="999920" >Porsche 981 Boxster S</option>
                                        <option value="999946" >Porsche Panamera GTS</option>
                                      </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="carAus">
                <select name="pyt-car" id="pyt-car">
                    <option value="%" >Any Car...</option>

                                        <option value="999980" >Ferrari F12</option>
                                        <option value="999996" >Jaguar F-Type V8</option>
                                        <option value="999998" >Lamborghini Aventador</option>
                                        <option value="9999101" selected="selected">Lamborghini Gallardo LP570</option>
                                        <option value="9999102" >Lamborghini Murcielago Roadster LP640</option>
                                        <option value="999945" >Porsche 911 C2S Cabrio</option>
                                        <option value="999994" >Porsche 911 C2S Coupe</option>
                                        <option value="999920" >Porsche 981 Boxster S</option>
                                      </select>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><select name="pyt-month" id="pyt-month">
                  <option value="%" selected="selected">Any Month...</option>
                                    <option value="01">January</option>
                                    <option value="02">February</option>
                                    <option value="03">March</option>
                                    <option value="04">April</option>
                                    <option value="05">May</option>
                                    <option value="06">June</option>
                                    <option value="07">July</option>
                                    <option value="08">August</option>
                                    <option value="09">September</option>
                                    <option value="10">October</option>
                                    <option value="11">November</option>
                                    <option value="12">December</option>
                                  </select></td>
                <td><select name="pyt-style" id="pyt-style">
                  <option value="%" selected="selected">Any Break Style...</option>
                                    <option value="8881" >Gourmet &amp; Wine</option>
                                    <option value="8882" >Historic &amp; Castles</option>
                                    <option value="8885" >Honeymoon & Romantic</option>
                                    <option value="88811" >Greatest Driver Roads</option>
                                    <option value="88812" >James Bond Inspired</option>
                                    <option value="88813" >Jet Set</option>
                                    <option value="88814" >Multi Country Tours</option>
                                    <option value="88815" >Porsche Celebration</option>
                                    <option value="88816" >Natural spas</option>
                                  </select></td>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Refine Results" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
      </form>
```

It I remove the initial jquery that listens for the POST and hides the DIVS
i.e.

```
if (countryid == "%") {
$('.carAll').css('display', 'block');
$('.carSw').css('display', 'none');
$('.carFr').css('display', 'none');
$('.carIt').css('display', 'none');
$('.carGer').css('display', 'none');
$('.carAus').css('display', 'none');
}
```

then it all works fine, however, when the page loads, it returns the full list of cars, but I want it to remember that I've selected a country and only show the DIV related to that country and hide the other DIVS until another country is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that all your car selects have the same `name`. The fact they are not visible to the user does not mean that they are not posted. In fact all of them are posted when the form is submitted, but only the last one (carAus) is picked by the server. You can verify this easily - just changed order of your car selects and see what happens.

To resolve this problem you need not only hide the select, but also disable it so that it is not submitted to the server. This can be done like this:

```
$(".carSw").prop('disabled', true);     //disabled
$(".carSw").prop('disabled', false);    //enabled
```

For example, in your case:

```
if($(this).val() == "%"){
    $('.carAll').css('display', 'block');
    $('.carAll').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
    $('.carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

the same for other cases. Note that [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) is used here to simplify things a bit.

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius! ...I was hoping it was something I'd overlooked.

We've got a little trophy for 'king of the lab' ...an award for the person who fixes a mind-numbing problem. So I've put it on next to the window for you (so you might see it from Street View LOL)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks what an oversight on the 'disabled' tag.

I didn't use multiple selectors as I was trying to simplify the code so that there were no gremlins. (in a previous job multiple selectors caused some bizarre issues after 3 were listed). but I've tidied that up for now.

The finished code now looks like this and works flawlessly...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var countryid = "<?php echo $_POST['pyt-country'] ; ?>";


             if(countryid == "%"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carAll').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if(countryid == "1"){
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carSw').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if(countryid == "2"){
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carFr').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if(countryid == "3"){
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carIt').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if(countryid == "4"){
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carGer').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if(countryid == "5"){
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carAus').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer').prop('disabled', true);
                }   




        $('#pyt-country').change(function () {
            if($(this).val() == "%"){
                $('.carAll').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carAll').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if($(this).val() == "1"){
                $('.carSw').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carSw').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if($(this).val() == "2"){
                $('.carFr').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carFr').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carIt, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if($(this).val() == "3"){
                $('.carIt').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carIt').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carGer, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carGer, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if($(this).val() == "4"){
                $('.carGer').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carGer').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carAus').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carAus').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            if($(this).val() == "5"){
                $('.carAus').css('display', 'block');
                $('.carAus').prop('disabled', false);
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer').css('display', 'none');
                $('.carAll, .carSw, .carFr, .carIt, .carGer').prop('disabled', true);
                }
        });


});  // End eventlistener
</script>
```